# Where to put reactor.run() in a PyQt app?

Tags: python, pyqt, twisted

Having difficulty showing the window / connecting to server depending placement of reactor.run()

If I place reactor.run() before or after **retranslateUi(self, MainWindow)**, the chat server logs the connection as successful, but the UI doesn't load. If I place **reactor.run()** after **sys.exit(app.exec_())** the client is unable to connect, even though the UI loads.

What is the best solution ?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

from twisted.application import service, internet

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    #Note actual code lives here

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    #prepare the chat 
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost",1025,ChatClientFactory())
    reactor.run()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "    Search "))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))





class ChatClient(LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def lineReceived(self, data):
        self.factory.text_from_patient = "{:>10}".format(data) # store the data so we can write to textedit

        self.textEdit.appendPlainText("\n"+ self.factory.text_from_patient)


class ChatClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    text_from_patient = " " # text to contain data sent from the user

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return ChatClient(self)


    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        reactor.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `reactor.run()` runs loop which works all time, and `app.exec_()` runs loop which works all time. `twister` should have special loop which you can use in place of `app.exec_()`

Comment: @furas I'm aware of that. can you please provide an example?

Comment: I can't give example. Using Google I found only modules [qt-reactor](https://pypi.org/project/qt-reactor/), [qt5reactor](https://pypi.org/project/qt5reactor/). Probably using this modules you can use `reactor.run()` instead of `app.exec_()`

Comment: @furas Awesome! I'll try it and post the outcome on here: success or failure

Answer (score 1):

Use [qt5reactor](https://pypi.org/project/qt5reactor/) and `reactor.run` in the usual way.

Comment: I'm new to qt5reactor. Can you please link to an example. I get this error when I place reactor in MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(reactor).......    TypeError: QMainWindow(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QtReactor'

Comment: I installed qt5reactor using: conda install -c conda-forge qt5reactor. Because I use spyder IDE. I didn't use pip install qt5reactor

Comment: I'm not familiar with spyder or conda, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found in the docs.

Twisted can be initialized after `QApplication.exec_()` with a call to
`reactor.runReturn()`.  Calling `reactor.stop()` will unhook twisted but
leave your Qt application running.

Your execution code should look like this

```
gui_app.exec_()
twisted.internet.reactor.runReturn()
```